# .Net Core MVC pattern equivalent in Express.js

Tags: node.js, .net, typescript, express, mean-stack

I am new to Node.js and Express.js, can someone guide me how to implement MVC in Node and Express project. I want to implement MVC pattern like we do in .Net Core projects with model, controller, services and repositories. Is there any way to check incoming request object whether its type is my custom model or not. I am open to typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExpressJS is an non-opinionated framework. What this means is that is gives you the basics needed to set up a server and some routes. Out of the box, it does not include any APIs to connect to databases or to implement design patterns such as MVC. These can, however, be implemented via middleware and other frameworks to handle the specifics.  In my personal projects, I've used sequelize.js to handle the Model part of the MVC, ExpressJS routes to handle the controller part, and Joi to validate incoming requests models to a specific structure.

Using a front end framework like React should handle the View part of MVC for you.

If you want something that already includes all MVC out-of-the-box, you might want to check out other frameworks like Sails.js and Loopback.io. I think they are both made on top of express, so what you've learned should apply there as well.

Comment: Can you please check this link https://www.programming-books.io/essential/nodejs/model-routes-controllers-services-code-structure-fe640ddd209647a08ffc5a36a58f5a98 i am reffering this link is it meaningful n correct

Comment: The link pretty much describes the same I mentioned, but it's using mongoose to handle the model part of MVC.

Comment: ok, can you please share any github link or some tutorial link which i Could refer

Answer (score 0):

Refer link

https://www.programming-books.io/essential/nodejs/model-routes-controllers-services-code-structure-fe640ddd209647a08ffc5a36a58f5a98

The link greatly explains about models, controller, router, schema etc